# Mail notification for stopped services in server

Tags: powershell

When i execute variable $test i see services with 4 columns `PSComputername,Name,StartMode,State` and its good. But when i like to send all this columns to e-mail i have problem with `$sr` variable. My report in mail looks like (serwer name is empty):

```
Serwer name:    
Start mode:     Auto
State:  Stopped
Naame:  clr_optimization_v4.0.30319_64
```

Script:

```
$servers = "server1"

$test = (gwmi win32_service -ComputerName $servers | 
where {$_.StartMode -eq “Auto” -and $_.State -eq "Stopped"}) | 
select PSComputername,Name,StartMode,State

$log = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\lalala.txt"
$filecontent = (Get-Content $log)
$rekord = 1 

foreach ($rekord in $test)
{
$sr=$rekord.Serwer
$sm=$rekord.StartMode
$st=$rekord.State
$n=$rekord.Name

$body += "
<table>
<tr>
<td>Nazwa serwera: </td> <td> $sr </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Typ uruchomienia: </td> <td> $sm </td>
<tr/>
<tr> 
<td>Stan uslugi: </td> <td> $st </td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Nazwa: </td> <td>$n </td>
</tr>
<br />
</table>
"

Add-Content $log "$sr,$st,$sm,$n"
Get-Content $log
}
Send-Mailmessage -smtpServer mail.domain.com -from serwisy@domain.com    -to user@domain.com -subject test -body $body -bodyasHTML -priority High
```

Comment: fix is $sr=$rekord.PSComputerName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You select `PSComputername` from the `gwmi win32_service -ComputerName $servers`-results, but use `$sr = $rekord.Serwer` later.

This should have been `$sr = $rekord.PSComputerName`

You might want to look over that HTML. Looks like it will create a separate table (With header) for every service per server.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $servers = "server1"

$test = (gwmi win32_service -ComputerName $servers | 
where {$_.StartMode -eq “Auto” -and $_.State -eq "Stopped"}) | 
select PSComputername,Name,StartMode,State

$log = ".\desktop\lalala.txt"
$filecontent = (Get-Content $log)
$rekord = 1 

foreach ($rekord in $test)
{
$sr = $rekord.PSComputerName
$sm = $rekord.StartMode
$st = $rekord.State
$n = $rekord.Name

$body += "
<table>
<tr>
<td>Nazwa serwera: </td> <td> $sr </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Typ uruchomienia: </td> <td> $sm </td>
<tr/>
<tr> 
<td>Stan uslugi: </td> <td> $st </td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Nazwa: </td> <td>$n </td>
</tr>
<br />
</table>
"

Add-Content $log "$sr,$st,$sm,$n"
Get-Content $log
}
Send-Mailmessage -smtpServer mail.domain.com -from serwisy@domain.com    -to user@domain.com -subject test -body $body -bodyasHTML -priority High
```

I fixed some of your code, but you have to fix the HTML bit.
But the main problem was that you selected `PSComputername` but used `$rekord.serwer`